# How to set RGB color from database

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, ios5, uilabel

I'm new in iphone development.i want to set uilabel's background color from the database..i already stored RGB color into the database.but i'm not getting the background color.

```
const char *dbpath = [database_Path UTF8String];
sqlite3_stmt    *statement;
[category_array removeAllObjects];
[category_arrDictionary removeAllObjects];
if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &Payer_DB) == SQLITE_OK)
{
    NSString *querySQL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT * FROM Expense_Category"];

    const char *query_stmt = [querySQL UTF8String];

    if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(Payer_DB,query_stmt, -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
    {
        while (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW)
        {
            //              NSLog(@"%i",SQLITE_ROW);
            NSMutableString *Category_Id = [[NSMutableString alloc]initWithUTF8String:(const char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 0)];
            NSMutableString *Category_Name = [[NSMutableString alloc]initWithUTF8String:(const char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 1)];
            NSMutableString *Category_Image = [[NSMutableString alloc]initWithUTF8String:(const char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 2)];
            NSMutableString *Category_Color = [[NSMutableString alloc]initWithUTF8String:(const char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 3)];
            NSLog(@"%@",Category_Color);

            [category_arrDictionary setObject:[NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:Category_Name,Category_Image,Category_Color,nil] forKey:Category_Id];
            [category_array addObject:Category_Id];
        }
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"Value updated");
    }
    sqlite3_finalize(statement);
    sqlite3_close(Payer_DB);
}
```

}

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath  *)indexPath 
{
    UILabel *lblCatColor = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(230,10, 70, 40)];
    [lblCatColor setBackgroundColor:[[category_arrDictionary valueForKey:[category_array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]] objectAtIndex:3]];
    //lblCatColor.text = [[category_arrDictionary valueForKey:[category_array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]] objectAtIndex:3];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:lblCatColor];

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: how you store your RGB value? means at which format.

Comment: 199.0,21.0,133.0 this is the format

Comment: what you get in category_arrDictionary ?

Comment: NSLog("%@",[[category_arrDictionary valueForKey:[category_array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]] objectAtIndex:3]);         which value is printed?

Comment: i'm getting tripname and color..i can able to display trip name in to the label..but i dnt have any idea to display background color of uilabel.

Comment: 123.0,104.0,238.0 i m getting RGB

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
NSString *strflg=[[category_arrDictionary valueForKey:[category_array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]] objectAtIndex:3]];

NSArray *colorArray=[strflg componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
float red;
float green;
float blue;

for (int j=0;j<[colorArray count]; j++) {
    if (j==0) {
        red=[[colorArray objectAtIndex:j] floatValue];
    }
    else if (j==1)
    {
        green=[[colorArray objectAtIndex:j] floatValue];
    }
    else{
        blue=[[colorArray objectAtIndex:j] floatValue];
    }
}

[lblCatColor setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:red/255.0f green:green/255.0f blue:blue/255.0f alpha:1.0]];
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to write a small method to parse the string you're extracting from the DB and create a `UIColor` from it. You can't directly set the color of the label using a string.

Comment: However, UIColor conforms to NSCoding so you should be able to store it as a BLOB.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to use this one. 
Your dictionary will give you a string and after that you should seperate your component and then put your red,green and blue value on the place of red,green and blue variable.

```
[lblCatColor setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:red/255.0f green:green/255.0f blue:blue/255.0f alpha:1.0f]];
```

Answer (score 0):

its may help you

```
NSString *strflg=[[category_arrDictionary valueForKey:[category_array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]] objectAtIndex:3]];

NSArray *colorArray=[strflg componentsSeparatedByString:@","];

[lblCatColor setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:[[colorArray objectAtIndex:0] floatValue]/255.0f green:[[colorArray objectAtIndex:1] floatValue]/255.0f blue:[[colorArray objectAtIndex:2] floatValue]/255.0f alpha:1.0]];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  [[category_arrDictionary valueForKey:[category_array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]] objectAtIndex:3] returns NSString like 199.0,21.0,133.0.
```

The following code will help you...

```
 NSString *colorFormat  = [[category_arrDictionary valueForKey:[category_array      objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]] objectAtIndex:3];
 NSArray *colorArr      = [[colorFormat componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
 float red              = [[colorArr objectAtIndex:0]floatValue];
 float green            = [[colorArr objectAtIndex:1]floatValue];
 float blue         = [[colorArr objectAtIndex:2]floatValue];

 [lblCatColor setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:(red/255.0) green:(green/255.0) blue:(blue/255.0) alpha:1.0]];
```

Answer (score 0):

Use following code snippet to create `UIColor` from `NSString`

```
NSString *rgbstr = @"123.0,104.0,238.0";
NSArray *arrRGB = [rgbstr componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
UIColor *color = [UIColor colorWithRed:[arrRGB[0] floatValue]/255.0f green:[arrRGB[1] floatValue]/255.0f blue:[arrRGB[2] floatValue]/255.0f alpha:1.0f];
```